# Proguard JavascriptInterface <print>

Tags: android, printing, webview

i have problems with proguard to Export a apk.
Proguard says: proguard.ParseException: Expecting class member name before ';'
For this line : print;

I need this for this in my class:

```
public class JIFace {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void print(String data) {
```

When i removed it from Progurad the Interface dont be call.

Progurad:

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}

-keepattributes JavascriptInterface

-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keep public class com.imh.sos.WebCPU_Mail$JIFace
-keep public class * implements com.imh.sos.WebCPU_Mail$JIFace
-keepclassmembers class com.imh.sos.WebCPU_Mail$JIFace { 
    <methods>; 
}


-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keep public class com.imh.sos.WebCPU_Mail$print
-keep public class * implements com.imh.sos.WebCPU_Mail$print
-keepclassmembers class  com.imh.sos.WebCPU_Mail$print { 
    <methods>; 
}




-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keep public class com.imh.sos.WebCPU_Mail$JIFace
-keep public class * implements com.imh.sos.WebCPU_Mail$JIFace
-keepclassmembers class com.imh.sos.WebCPU_Mail$JIFace { 
    <print>; 
}

-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keep public class com.imh.sos.WebCPU_Mail$print
-keep public class * implements com.imh.sos.WebCPU_Mail$print
-keepclassmembers class com.imh.sos.WebCPU_Mail$print { 
    <print>; 
}
```

SDK is 19.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
-keep public class package_name.activity_name$MyJavaScriptInterface

-keep public class * implements package_name.activity_name$MyJavaScriptInterface
-keepclassmembers class package_name.activity_name$MyJavaScriptInterface {
<methods>;}

-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
```